# I can't seem to connect MySQL Workbench to a server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have no knowledge of programming or anything beyond basic computer skills, so I'm probably jumping the gun on this.

Anyway, I am trying to understand SQL, so I downloaded MySQL Workbench, Utilities, and MySQL Server. 
When I try to make a connection (on the start page of MySQL Workbench) I get an error code that reads:

```
"Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root. Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)"
```

I left the default settings (hostname: **127.0.0.1**, port: **3306**, user: **root**, no password) but I still get this error message.

What should I do? I already downloaded MySQL Server but I don't even know how to make sure it is running.

I am using a MacBook Air with OS X Yosemite (v. 10.10.2)

Thank you, I appreciate any help!

Comment: Is mysql server started?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for Stack Overflow as it is not about programming.

Comment: server is not started as Mark States !

Comment: MySQL is a bit of a wrangly one. I like YT vids for setups .  sorry for the DV's , we like posts with a little more code/efforts

Answer (score 0):

It very much sounds like your server is not running. If you use a current version of MySQL Workbench you should however still be allowed to "open" a connection, even if the server is not running. MySQL Workbench has an admin section where you can control your server, including starting it up or shutting it down.

When you open a connection with an unavailable server you see something like this:

[image]

Switch to the Startup/Shutdown section and click the "Start Server" button:

[image]

If all goes well you see a number of startup messages in the log window and status label changes to "running" (and becomes green). Additionally, the Session window in the lower left corner should now show you some details about your server.

You can now close the admin tab and start running queries in an sql tab.